# %appdata%, открывание

Tags: c#, файлы

У меня есть вот такой код:

```cs
string[] rea = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\owner\\source\\repos\\Schedule v2.3\\test.txt");
```

Как мне после `File.ReadAllLines` вставить `%appdata%\\test.txt`? Что бы appdata открывалась на любом компьютере. А если он не найдёт такой файл, то создавал его. Нужен пример кода.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А как мне сделать что бы если файл не находило то создавало новый?

Comment: `Path.Exists`, прочитайте про классы `DirectoryInfo`, `FileInfo`, `Path`, `Environment`, там всё что нужно есть для работы с файлами. Проверять существует путь или нет лучше конечно через `Path`, потому что он независим от платформы, если мне не изменяет память.

Comment: а как это можно сделать кодом?

Comment: В документации по этим классам и их методам показано, как